# Have pictures appear and hide based on cell content

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble getting this code to cooperate with me. I assume it can be simplified to a With function but i'm not sure on how to achieve it.

```
If Worksheets("input").Range("B13").Value = "special text" Then
    Worksheets("Customer Report").Pictures("Picture5").Visible = True
    Worksheets("Customer Report").Pictures("Picture6").Visible = False
Else
    Worksheets("Customer Report").Pictures("Picture5").Visible = False
    Worksheets("Customer Report").Pictures("Picture6").Visible = True
End If
```

The goal is to have Picture5 appear if B13 on another sheet reads "special text" and to have Picture6 appear if B13 reads any other text.

Comment: Are you using this code on worksheet change?

Comment: try `.Shapes` in place of `.Pictures`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is Shapes not Pictures.

And just like the answer I gave you last time the If is not needed.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Worksheets("input").Range("B13")
With Worksheets("Customer Report")
    .Shapes("Picture5").Visible = rng.Value = "special text"
    .Shapes("Picture6").Visible = Not rng.Value = "special text"
End With
```